# Output 12-25V from Arduino Mega

Tags: arduino-mega, stepper

I am currently building my first Arduino project : a car that you can control from your computer. I have my Arduino Mega that outputs 3.3 or 5V and my stepper that receives 12-25V, how can I make my Arduino digitally write something to that stepper?

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Stepper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an H-bridge motor driver. They can use arduino signals to control higher voltages without damaging the arduino. Check out the  [L298N](http://m.gearbest.com/other-accessories/pp_226466.html) from gearbest. It's cheap but will probably do the trick if you're not using too much current.

It can supply about 1A through each gate at 5-30V.

[this video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=QixPEZgRVzM) should help explain it. (I haven't watched the video but it seems like it got good feedback).